# When creating a gist, how do I search for the previous/next match?

Tags: github, gist

If I press the search shortcut in my browser while creating/editing a gist, it pops up a little search on the header:

[image]

I haven't found any documentation on this functionality. If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it jumps to a match, the search disappears, and all other matches are highlighted: so far so good.

But I can't figure out how to navigate from one match to the next with my keyboard; if I press any key after I've pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it edits the document. **How do I jump to the previous/next matching term with my keyboard?**

For context, I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts you are searching for are as follows:

**Find next**
Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
Mac/Linux: <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

**Find previous**
Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
Mac/Linux: <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

*More shortcuts can be found on the page about [Keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-github/keyboard-shortcuts) in the GitHub Docs.*